After creating a CNAME file in the repo, GitHub Pages will still not serve on a custom domain
Per the instructions I've created the CNAME file


In the "Code and automation" section of the sidebar, click  Pages.

Under "Custom domain", type your custom domain, then click Save. If you are publishing your site from a branch, this will create a commit that adds a CNAME file directly to the root of your source branch. If you are publishing your site with a custom GitHub Actions workflow, no CNAME file is created, so you need to create one manually (containing only a line of text with your custom domain). For more information about your publishing source, see "Configuring a publishing source for your GitHub Pages site."



However, creating the CNAME file didn't seem to do it. It made no difference and I'm still getting the 404.

For me this is because I lacked admin perms. I read that as "if this, that; [BUT], if this, other thing".  I should have read it as, "if this, that; [AND], if this, other thing".
That is to say, someone still had to do

Under "Custom domain", type your custom domain, then click Save.


This is what I saw under the UI For Code and automation → Pages


And this is what a coworker with different perms saw,



In our case, I had the role "maintain" and my coworker had the role "admin"
